# Is it possible to deploy an ASP.NET application to SharePoint using the solution deployment mechanism?

Tags: sharepoint

After reading this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297200.aspx), I'm thinking it's not possible.  However, I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application that I need to put in our SharePoint environment.  I know it is possible following the steps outlined in the article, but our SP admins only accept WSP packages for deployment into the enterprise environment.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your ASP.NET application need SharePoint context, e.g. will be accessed via ~site/_layouts/yourapp/default.aspx? If so, this is a simple task for WSPBuilder (wspbuilder.codeplex.com). If it doesn't need sharepoint context, then WSPs are the wrong solution to the wrong question. You should be looking at MSDeploy instead (or more reasonably, your infrastructure folks should be)

Have a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/89499dea-6178-478a-a994-cfb671143049/

-Oisin

Comment: Yes, my app uses the SP context.  I did not know about WSPBuilder, but it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you just used the page viewer web part.  That allows you to simply embed the application within sharepoint.  Or are you actually programming against sharepoint data / code ?